# Unrecognized token in source text

Tags: npm, babeljs

Can somebody help me with this one? I really don't know why is this happening.

```js
Unrecognized token in source text.
At line:1 char:13
+ npm install  <<<< @babel/core @babel/cli --save-dev
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnrecognizedToken
```

Comment: Using 'git bash' instead of the PowerShell solves my problem on windows

Comment: Hey @AMD, you can put your comment as a new answer, because it works for me! Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Got the same error. You could try enclosing the text containing at-sign within apostrophes ('), like this:

```
npm install --save-dev '@babel/core' '@babel/cli'
```

Got the answer right here: https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/issues/1114

Answer (score 1):

Hope you ran the below from npm prompt

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli
```